# Is there way to store last broadcast emit - socket.io and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, socket.io

I am a beginner with Socket.io + Node.js. I have the following code that brings in a data object such as following:

**client side**

```
socket.on('move', function (data) {
just_moved=data.id;
x=data.x;
y=data.y;
})
```

**server side**

```
WebArch.prototype.moveElement = function(obj, x0, y0){
socket.emit('move', {id:obj.attr("id"), x:x0, y:y0});
}
```

**'move'** event is triggered when an SVG element is dragged on canvas. I would like to know if there's a way that I could store(save in a variable or an object) only the last emit that is made when the element is dragged. Can a **mouseup** event condition be placed inside the function or any other method to achieve this?

Comment: Is one of the peers supposed to be a web browser? Which one do you want to be saving the event? If you want to emit a mouseup, then go ahead and do so.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the event "dragend" was what I needed.